# Combine rows based on index or column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have three dataframes: df1, df2, df3. I am trying to add a list of ART_UNIT do df1.

df1 is 260846 rows x 4 columns:

```
Index    SYMBOL    level  not-allocatable  additional-only
0        A         2             True            False
1        A01       4             True            False
2        A01B      5             True            False
3        A01B1/00  7            False            False
4        A01B1/02  8            False            False
5        A01B1/022 9            False            False
6        A01B1/024 9            False            False
7        A01B1/026 9            False            False
```

df2 is 941516 rows x 2 columns:

```
Index       CLASSIFICATION_SYMBOL_CD  ART_UNIT
0                     A44C27/00       3715
1                    A44C27/001       2015
2                    A44C27/001       3715
3                    A44C27/001       2615
4                    A44C27/005       2815
5                    A44C27/006       3725
6                    A44C27/007       3215
7                    A44C27/008       3715
8                     F41A33/00       3715
9                     F41A33/02       3715
10                    F41A33/04       3715
11                    F41A33/06       3715
12                    G07C13/00       3715
13                   G07C13/005       3715
14                    G07C13/02       3716
```

And df3 is the same format as df2, but has 673023 rows x 2 columns

The `'CLASSIFICATION_SYMBOL_CD'` in df2 and df3 are not unique.

For each `'CLASSIFICATION_SYMBOL_CD'` in df2 and df3, I want to find the same string in df1 `'SYMBOL'` and add a new column to df1 `'ART_UNIT'` that contains all of the `'ART_UNIT'` from df2 and df3.

For example, in df2, `'CLASSIFICATION_SYMBOL_CD'` A44C27/001 has `ART_UNIT` 2015, 3715, and 2615.

**I want to write those `ART_UNIT` to the correct row in df1 so that is reads:**

```
Index    SYMBOL      level  not-allocatable  additional-only  ART_UNIT
211        A44C27/001  2             True            False    [2015, 3715, 2615]
```

So far, I've tried to group df2/df3 by `'CLASSIFICATION_SYMBOL_CD'`

```
gp = df2.groupby(['CLASSIFICATION_SYMBOL_CD'])
for x in df2['CLASSIFICATION_SYMBOL_CD'].unique():
    df2_g = gp.get_group(x)
```

Which gives me:

```
Index       CLASSIFICATION_SYMBOL_CD    ART_UNIT
1354        A61N1/3714                  3762
117752      A61N1/3714                  3766
347573      A61N1/3714                  3736
548026      A61N1/3714                  3762
560771      A61N1/3714                  3762
566120      A61N1/3714                  3766
566178      A61N1/3714                  3762
799486      A61N1/3714                  3736
802408      A61N1/3714                  3736
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `df2` and `df3` have the same format concatentate them first.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat([df2, df3])
```

Then to get the lists of all art units, `groupby` and apply list.

```
df = df.groupby('CLASSIFICATION_SYMBOL_CD').ART_UNIT.apply(list).reset_index()
#   CLASSIFICATION_SYMBOL_CD            ART_UNIT
#0                 A44C27/00              [3715]
#1                A44C27/001  [2015, 3715, 2615]
#2                A44C27/005              [2815]
#3                A44C27/006              [3725]
#...
```

Finally, bring this information to `df1` with a merge (you could map or something else too). Rename the column first to have less to clean up after the merge.

```
df = df.rename(columns={'CLASSIFICATION_SYMBOL_CD': 'SYMBOL'})
df1 = df1.merge(df, on='SYMBOL', how='left')
```

Output:

```
   Index     SYMBOL  level  not-allocatable  additional-only ART_UNIT
0      0          A      2             True            False      NaN
1      1        A01      4             True            False      NaN
2      2       A01B      5             True            False      NaN
3      3   A01B1/00      7            False            False      NaN
4      4   A01B1/02      8            False            False      NaN
5      5  A01B1/022      9            False            False      NaN
6      6  A01B1/024      9            False            False      NaN
7      7  A01B1/026      9            False            False      NaN
```

Sadly, you didn't provide any overlapping SYMBOLs in `df1`, so nothing merged. But this will work with your full data.

Comment: If you don’t want duplicates in the list you might consider applying set instead of list after the groupby